# Separate a string in Swift

Tags: swift, string, substring

How can I get the value after the colon?

Example string: "aaa:test , bbb:test , ccc:test"

I would have to recognize *aaa:*, *bbb:*, *ccc:* to get the value after the colon.

**There's also a special case:** "aaa:aaa: , bbb:bbb, , ccc:test"

The value may or may not have exactly the same word as the variable. Also, the value may contain a comma.

Comment: the solution of that can't handle the special case i mentioned above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use componenetSeparatedBy method of String. I am assuming that all the key-value will be separated by " , "

```
   let wordsArr = "aaa:test: , bbb:test,a , ccc:test".components(separatedBy: " , ") as [String]
```

This will give you an array with words {[aaa:test:] , [ bbb:test,a] , [ccc:test]}

```
    var aaa, bbb, ccc : String?


    for (_,keyValueWords) in wordsArr.enumerated()  {

        var strKeyValuePair = keyValueWords
        if strKeyValuePair.hasPrefix("aaa:") {
            aaa = String(strKeyValuePair.characters.dropFirst(4))
        }
        else if strKeyValuePair.hasPrefix("bbb:"){
            bbb = String(strKeyValuePair.characters.dropFirst(4))

        }else  if strKeyValuePair.hasPrefix("ccc:"){
            ccc = String(strKeyValuePair.characters.dropFirst(4))
        }

    }

    print("aaa=\(aaa!) , bbb=\(bbb!) , ccc=\(ccc!)")
```

Comment: but i have to recognise where the value belongs to. beacuse sometimes the string may just have "bbb:test , ccc:test". the string is dynamic.

Comment: So if the string is "bbb:test , ccc:test" , what do you want in output ?

Comment: i will create 5 variables, var aaa , var bbb, var ccc, var ddd, var eee, and i have to get the corresponding values into these variables

Comment: Jose's solution is really nice.  
@Henry: this is my improved solution:  

let elements = "aaa:test, bbb:test, ccc:test".components(separatedBy: ", ") // a comma and a space  

for e in elements {  
    print(e.components(separatedBy: ":"))  
}

Comment: thanks @ngbaanh. i was editing my answer exactly like what you thought of :)

Comment: thank you very much.  @Jen Jose, i have added a special case on my question. Can this answer handle the special case as well?

Comment: this solution will give array like {[aaa:aaa:] , [ bbb:test] , [] , [ccc:test]} . so that would skip the extra comma ? is that okay ?

Comment: No, the answer should also contain extra comma and semicolon if the value has those.

Comment: thanks a lot, but how if the case is " aaa:test:, bbb:test, ccc:test,"  actually it separate by ", "

Comment: I don't know your exact requirement but I believe for such scenarios the separator string should be a fixed unique string that is not repeated in the value part of the String.